# Include script in local directory from a dynamic path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a game engine intended to support modding, which includes loading a custom mod directory with an init script. I can't find a clear answer as to the best way of dynamically loading a script from a string variable path. The name of the active mod will likely be specified as a script parameter: While I know the following example is probably not correct unless this is in fact allowed, it's intuitively what I'm thinking of doing in my `init.py` unless a more correct way exists.

```
import sys
import "mods/" + sys.argv[1] + "/init.py"
```

Comment: Is "telling folks that they need to edit the `__init__.py` in the mod dir so that the loader adds their mod" an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import a module as string, but you could make use of [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

main.py:

```
import importlib
import sys

# Note: Dot notation!
myMod = importlib.import_module("mods." + sys.argv[1].strip() + ".init")
myMod.hello()
```

init.py:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello from init!")
```

Directory structure:

```
.
├── main.py
└── mods
    └── foo
        └── init.py
```

Calling main.py, results in:

```
python main.py foo
Hello from init!
```